# Understanding private "with link" visualizations in Carto?

Tags: carto, visualisation, carto-js, privacy

We are creating web dashboards for a small number of customers (~5) in which each customer can view private business-related statistics.

We want to embed some visualizations inside the dashboards. The visualizations are static, i.e. the customers will not be able to change the "SQL query" (by "static" we do not mean "static image" - zooming, dragging and mouse-hovering should still work).

The data and the visualizations should be kept private as they may have commercially sensitive value.

Password protected visualizations will be annoying to the costumers - they already entered a password when they logged in to the dashboard.

Is the "With link" privacy mode what we need? i.e. simply create an iframe to embed the visualization, and assume that guessing the url is practically impossible.

What happens if we accidentally switch to a "Public" mode?

Where exactly is the visualization published?

Comment: OK, I just found out that the public visualizations can be seen from https://<username>.cartodb.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say in your comment, "Public" visualizations can be seen in your public profile.

"Public with link" visualizations are public too, with the simple difference that they're not listed in your profile.

If you're building "public with link" visualizations from private tables, no one will be able to see the contents on your table but the information you decide to put in the map.

This means that if you include some data in the infowindows and the own visual data which is mapped both will be accessible for everyone that has the link.

It exists the possibility that someone else can get to your visualizations. This is very unlikely, as IDs are created randomly, but guessing the ID of your visualization + your username will render the map if the URL is requested.

CartoDB won't publish the link to your public with link visualizations or tables anywhere, but take into account that anyone that you send the link may be able to spread it. Also, if you're including the URL in a public website, a Google crawler for example may get it.

If your dashboards will be accessed under authentication, then I wouldn't worry too much and I'd personally use "public with link vizs + private tables". This is the same behaviour than building a [named map](http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/maps-api.html) created via Javascript.

Data cannot be queried (as table is private) and the visualization itself is created through a named map which is automatically created by the CartoDB Editor.

If you need your users to query the data in a private way, the way to go would be using named maps with variables.

Comment: Thanks. In my case the visualizations themselves are also sensitive, not only the raw data. I noticed that the "share link" feature creates a short url to the visualization. This url is easier to "guess". Is it possible to turn this feature off?